Query to retrieve the translated knowledge article with data categories

SELECT Id, Title, Language, ArticleNumber, Summary,
(
SELECT Id, DataCategoryName, DataCategoryGroupName
FROM DataCategorySelections
)
FROM Knowledge__kav
WHERE PublishStatus = 'Online' AND Language = 'fr'

I am using this query to get all the data of knowledge article with data category but there is some issue here when I query it for en_US I get all the articles with proper data category and as soon as I change the language to Fr or De I only see these fields(Id, Title, Language, ArticleNumber, Summary) and nothing related to data category.
What is the issue here please can someone help me with this?

Check that the data categories are properly configured and assigned to the articles in all required languages and also, the data categories and their translations are correctly set up. Check that the user has the necessary permissions to view data categories in the specified languages. This can be done by reviewing the user's profile and permission sets.
For more information refer to these: - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.knowledge_translation_overview.htm&type=5 -https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383256&type=1
